# react router don't show nested route

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Following the [docs](https://rackt.github.io/react-router/),
I've got this code:

```jsx
var React = require('react');
var Router = require('react-router');
var Route = Router.Route;
var RouteHandler = Router.RouteHandler;
var Link = Router.Link;

var About = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return <h2>About</h2>;
    }
});

var Inbox = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return <h2>Inbox</h2>;
    }
});

var Home = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return <h2>Home</h2>;
    }
});

var Message = React.createClass({
    componentDidMount: function () {
        // from the path `/inbox/messages/:id`
        var id = this.props.params.id;
        console.log('id',id);
    },
    render () {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Message  {this.props.params.id}</h1>
            </div>
        );
    }
});

var App = React.createClass({
    render () {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>App</h1>
                <ul>
                    <li><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
                    <li><Link to="about">About</Link></li>
                    <li><Link to="inbox">Inbox</Link></li>
                    <li><Link to="message" params={ {id: 'myid'} }>Inbox message</Link></li>
                </ul>
                <RouteHandler {...this.props}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
});

// declare our routes and their hierarchy
var routes = (
    <Route handler={App}>
        <Route name="home" path="/" handler={Home}/>
        <Route name="about" path="/about" handler={About}/>
        <Route name="inbox" path="/inbox" handler={Inbox}>
            <Route name="message" path="/messages/:id" handler={Message}/>
        </Route>
    </Route>
);

Router.run(routes, Router.HashLocation, (Root, state) => {
    var params = state.params;
    React.render(<Root  params={params} />, document.body);
});
```

I'm wondering why on earth if I click on **In box message** link I see 
Inbox and not Message

What's wrong ?

Comment: is there anything in your console? if message cant render, it would look like your inbox renders instead because theyre nested.

Comment: @PhilVarg No, there is no id in the console.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you substitute the message route with `<DefaultRoute handler={Message} />?`

Answer (score 0):

what version of react router is this? On pre-version 1.0 (might still work in 1.0), you can pass params in like so:

```
<Link to="message" params={ {id: myid} }>In box message</Link>
```